# Need of typecasting before ceil

Tags: java

I am going through the following code in Java:

```
public float a1 = 0.10f;

int Increments;

if(TotalTime > 0)
                {
                    Increments = (int) ceil(TotalTime / Increment1);                    
                    amount = round(Increments * a1, 4);
                }    


    Where,          

    TotalTime and Increment1 are integers
```

My questions is, Why do we need to typecast to integer just before `ceil` as done in the following line of code above?

```
Increments = (int) ceil(TotalTime / Increment1);
```

Comment: `ceil` as in `Math.ceil()` or a function you wrote?

Comment: You are performing integer division, so ceiling this result will do nothing, you will keep the result of the division.

Comment: @C.B. Yes it's the `Math.ceil()` function from `import static java.lang.Math.ceil;`

Comment: @ZouZou So, `(int)` is required?

Comment: @John You need to cast one of the argument as double when performing the division. Ex: `(double)TotalTime / Increment1`

Answer (score 0):

Because `Math.ceil` (I suppose it's a static import there) returns a `double`. As you make a restriction of the converted value (by converting to a less precise type), you need to do the conversion explicitly.

Also, please note that the argument you pass to `ceil` is the ratio of two integers, which is also an integer. So you're in danger of losing precision. Moreover, applying `ceil` to an integer is redundant, as it will return that integer itself. And the last remark: `ceil` expects a `double` as its argument. In this case, you pass an `int`, but the conversion is done implicitly, because it is done from a less precise to a more precise type.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that [`Math.ceil` returns a `double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29). You cannot implicitly cast from a `double` to an `int`. Trying to compile this:

```
double d = 2.1;
int i = d;
```

Gives you:

```
dur.java:4: possible loss of precision
found   : double
required: int
    int i = d;
            ^
1 error
```

As the error message states, the reason is that you might lose precision, so the compiler wants to be sure that you really want to allow this loss. You do this by making the cast explicit:

```
int i = (int)d;
```

---

Note that even so, your code won't do what you expect.

```
int i = 10;
int j = 3;
int k = (int)Math.ceil(i/j);
System.out.println(k); //outputs '3'
```

The reason is that `i / j` performs integer division if both `i` and `j` are integers, which rounds down. `i / j` is already `3`, and all `Math.ceil` does is return `3.0`, which then again gets casted to `3`. You want to do floating point division instead, which is done when one or both of `i` and `j` are floating point types. You can achieve this by casting one of the integers to a double before doing the division:

```
int i = 10;
int j = 3;
int k = (int)Math.ceil((double)i/j);
System.out.println(k); //outputs '4'
```